# How to restart a process in a git hook on linux

Tags: php, bash, git, lumen

I am writing a webservice using Laravel's Lumen. I want to use a git hook to update the webservice after a commit to the central repository. According to lumen's documentation I must start lumen using this command:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

This creates a php process. A very clumsy way to do it would be to use `killall php` before the above command to kill the process in the git hook, but there must be a better way. Perhaps a way to record the pid, or something more specific to lumen.

Comment: Given how long it takes to start (and sometimes even stop) a service like this, maybe doing it synchronously in a git hook isn't the best solution. Could the service provide its own "restart me" endpoint that the hook uses?

Comment: php inbuilt server is for developement, besides im not sure why you would need to restart the process, how is the server affecting your deployment?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If I've made changes to the code the server is running it only makes sense to restart the server, no? I think Lumen works kind of like node. Though perhaps I am mistaken, which is what is causing the confusion

Comment: No php code is not like node code, its not loaded into the memory/process on startup. With php its loaded upon request so restarting the server does nothing apart from maybe clear opcache if your using it, but if code has changed it makes no difference.

Comment: If you were making a php extension that would be a valid reason to restart the process.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Hmm, I just did some tests and I guess you are right. The php command in the documentation confused me. I kind of missed the significance of the -S option. I guess I could serve this from nginx or apache as well. Though I have to add that I think it's possible to write PHP that executes on load like node.js and serves a website. I don't see why one couldn't write a webserver in PHP if one were so inclined. Anyhow, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to manage this by supervisord:
(http://www.supervisord.org/)

If you configure your webservice as mylumenws
You can:

`sudo supervisorctl start/stop/restart mylumenws`

Laravel has an example running its Queues with supervisord:
(https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration)